# Parent POM dependency tree discovery for sub modules (Maven)

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have created a maven goal that outputs a dependency tree for a given maven project to a YAML file. Using the m2eclipse plugin for Eclipse Photon.

Currently when I run the goal against a parent project (using type pom when setting up dependency), the only dependency returned is on the pom for the specific parent. Is there any way to prevent me needing to run this goal against **all** of the projects underneath the parent?

Comment: First of all, `mvn dependency:tree` is the standard Maven goal to output the dependency tree (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html). It does not speak YAML, but other interesting formats.

Secondly, I don't see one should add a parent POM of a multi module project as a dependency to a project. Or is this just a "trick" to access it from your plugin?

Comment: More of a trick to access it from my plugin and write out it's dependencies.

Comment: What is the advantage of your plugin to just using `dependency:tree` ?

Comment: Sorry I might have misunderstood. I am using the dependency:tree goal in order to do this. Currently using the dependency:tree, I am able to create the dependency tree for any project I wish. I am looking for a way to be able to use a parent project to get the dependencies for all of its sub-modules rather than needing to do each individually.

Comment: If you run `mvn dependency:tree` on the module parent POM, you get the tree for each of the modules.

Comment: When I run from command line yes. But when I run my project from Eclipse, in the dependency file it only contains the line - <parent>:pom:<version>:compile

Comment: What exactly do you do in Eclipse?

Comment: Run my pom.xml against specific Maven projects to write out their dep trees to a file. Got the dependency plug in configured with outputFile, appendOutput and Verbose. During the 'generate-sources' phase is when I execute this goal. I can go more specific in messages, not enough characters for comment.

Comment: It would be great if you edit your question and append the relevant parts of your POM.

Answer (score 0):

Might need a little more information on this, but are your children poms of the parent specified as modules within the parent pom?

Example:

```
<parentPom>
  <modules>
    <module>/path/to/childA</module>
  </modules>
</parentPom>
```

Comment: Within the parent pom yes they are. I was wondering if maybe I needed to do something like this in my pom.xml.